# Crystal report show lines

Tags: crystal-reports

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/360VB.png)

I have some transactions in Crystal's report where data is taken from excel. As I have inserted a line in the details section. But I need to make the line thicker over the end of the transaction and after the end of the transaction I need to hide the line but in mine, it shows a line. I have inserted the picture of how it shows in my report. Please help with this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfgLI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just put the line before the output not after. That's what I'm doing all the time.